Health Connect(Android 14): App needs to be updated to continue syncing with Health Connect
The app works fine in Android 13 and below versions and syncs the data successfully.
When I try to connect to the Health Connect in Android 14, it shows this:
The Health Connect (Beta) app is being integrated with the Android system.
App needs to be updated to continue syncing with Health Connect
Can anyone please tell me why I am facing this issue, and how can I resolve this issue?

Ensure that your app's SDK version is compatible with Android 14. If you're using any third-party libraries or SDKs for health data syncing, make sure they are also compatible with the latest Android version.

On Android 14 the Health Connect app isn't installed anymore via the Play Store. It is a system app now coming with the OS and can be accessed in the settings. Apps that want to access the data (like yours) need to be updated to accomodate this change.
There is an overview that outlines the differences from the user's perspective. Follow the migration guide to make your app also work for Android 14.
